# Can I unlock infinite ammo without playing online?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

I got out my copy of Gears of War 3 recently. I am trying to unlock the infinite ammo mutator but I have to be playing multiplayer. However, I only have Silver and can't afford to buy Xbox Live Gold. I have to get combat engineer. Is there another way to earn them or enable badge earning in solo private?

Answer (score 2):

All medals can be earned while offline.

source: http://wikigameguides.com/Gears-of-War-3/wiki/Medals-15610 as well as personal experience

Comment: But combat engineer won't budge. I know I put up MORE than 5 fortifications on horde.

Comment: combat engineer is for upgrading fortifications I believe, not just placing them.

Comment: Then how come I don't have the infinite ammo mutator? I already have the combat engineer.